# How to use Rowspan in Gridview for 1st Column only

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

Need help to resolve a issue related with Gridview layout. I am trying to implement custome Gridview with Itemtemplate Columns using C#.Net language and want to include view using RowSpan property.

[image: As Below]

I tried to use below code but didn't work for me [Here](http://csharpdotnetfreak.blogspot.com/2009/07/merge-gridview-cells-columns-aspnet.html)

Please check the code which i used:

```
 protected void GridView31_DataBound1(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    for (int rowIndex = grdView31.Rows.Count - 2; rowIndex >= 0; rowIndex--)
    {
        GridViewRow gvRow = grdView31.Rows[rowIndex];
        GridViewRow gvPreviousRow = grdView31.Rows[rowIndex + 1];
        for (int cellCount = 0; cellCount < gvRow.Cells.Count; cellCount++)
        {
            if (gvRow.Cells[cellCount].Text == gvPreviousRow.Cells[cellCount].Text)
            {
                if (gvPreviousRow.Cells[cellCount].RowSpan < 2)
                {
                    gvRow.Cells[cellCount].RowSpan = 2;
                }
                else
                {
                    gvRow.Cells[cellCount].RowSpan =
                        gvPreviousRow.Cells[cellCount].RowSpan + 1;
                }
                gvPreviousRow.Cells[cellCount].Visible = false;
            }
        }
    }

}
```

But every time the `gvRow.Cells[cellCount].Text == gvPreviousRow.Cells[cellCount].Text` is blank.

Hence the grid is taking weird shapes. Don't know what is happening here.

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Use RowDataBound event instead:

```
void GridView31_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow )
    {
        if (e.Row.RowIndex % 4 == 0)
        {
            e.Row.Cells[0].Attributes.Add("rowspan", "4");
        }
        else
        {
            e.Row.Cells[0].Visible = false;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

```
 protected void GridView31_DataBound1(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    int i = 1;
    for (int rowIndex = grdView31.Rows.Count - 2; rowIndex >= 0; rowIndex--)
    {
        GridViewRow gvRow = grdView31.Rows[rowIndex];
        GridViewRow gvPreviousRow = grdView31.Rows[rowIndex + 1];

        if (i % 4 !=0)
        {
            if (gvPreviousRow.Cells[0].RowSpan < 2)
            {
                gvRow.Cells[0].RowSpan = 2;
            }
            else
            {
                gvRow.Cells[0].RowSpan = gvPreviousRow.Cells[0].RowSpan + 1;
            }
            gvPreviousRow.Cells[0].Visible = false;
        }
        i++;
    }
```

This worked our for me. Trial & error :)

Comment: @naveen i checked the above solution works perfect & yes much better than what i did :) Thanks naveen for sharing this

Comment: happy to help dude... :) but yuriys solution solves your prob right?

Answer (score 0):

```
    'VB.NET Code


Private Sub DG_Data_RowDataBound(sender As Object, e As System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridViewRowEventArgs) Handles DG_Data.RowDataBound
            Try

                'fusion , rowspan , colspan , 
                If e.Row.RowType = DataControlRowType.DataRow Then
                    If e.Row.RowIndex Mod 4 = 0 Then
                        e.Row.Cells(0).Attributes.Add("rowspan", "4")
                    Else
                        e.Row.Cells(0).Visible = False
                    End If
                End If



            Catch ex As Exception
                jq.msgErrorLog(ex)
            End Try
        End Sub
```