# Is it Possible to merge two cells in a datatable

Tags: c#, datatable

Is it Possible to merge two Columns to a single column for only  one row in a datatable using C#?
similar to Merge cells option of the excel

```
DataTable table = new DataTable();
table.Columns.Add("Column1",typeof (String))
table.Columns.Add("Column2",typeof (String))
table.Columns.Add("Column3",typeof (String))
table.rows.add(table.newrow());
```

i want to merge column2 and column3 for only first row of the Datatable.

Comment: Why would you do that?

Comment: `DataTable` is a data structure not a UI feature. Your visual control is the one that need to display the result of the 1,2,3... columns into a single cell. Look for binding values. It's easier to bind in WPF but still perfectly doable in Winforms. Search on the web for the following keywords with your visual control : `Binding, Data binding` you will find what you need. Otherwise if the control cant you will need to create a new column and iterate to fill that column with the value of the others concatenated and then bind the data to the control. Inefficient and harder to manager later on

Answer (score 1):

DataTable is not a visible aspect, there will be no need of merging 2 columns, please give the specific requirement. I don't think it is possible too.

Or better create different datatables and merge the datatables rather than merging the columns in a row.

Then in case of gridview scenario, you could have look here :-

[GridView with merged cells](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16147963/gridview-with-merged-cells)

Comment: i am using Datatable for a gridview to display in a winform. i want to show a heading for the gridview