# Using vb.net / ASP.NET and Gridview to do a command based on data in the row above

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, gridview

Trying to figure out how to code a command based on the content of the row above, I thought about using rowdatabound but that seems to only work with the current row and has no concept of the data around it?

My aim is to be able to look at data via Gridview (working without a problem) but if the above row of data's columns 1-4 match the current row to blank column 1-4 on the current row Example(in excel but of course i need it in ASP / VB.net) below:

[image: Example drawn up quickly in Excel]

What the Grid view should look like:

[image: Example 2]

I know the code will be pretty simple, but I have been starring at my screen for days trying to figure it out and still no luck :(.

Regards
Jamie

Comment: Do you want the blank cells or the [merged cells](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16147963/gridview-with-merged-cells)? Also are you using bound fields in your grid or using template fields.

Comment: Currently using standard gridview, no changes have been made to use template fields so guessing bound fields, also it doesn't matter about blanking the cells or merging them as the columns 1-4 will match but 5-9 will ALWAYS be different.

Comment: Have you gone through the link in my question ie http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16147963/gridview-with-merged-cells?lq=1?

Comment: @JamieB Do you want to fill empty in the duplicate row from Column 1-4 but still want to keep Column5-9 for that row?

Comment: @SivaGopal yes that would be my aim.

Comment: @Șhȇkhaṝ I think that may answer my question.