# Combine multiple rows with the same value into a single row with a list of that row's value

Tags: google-sheets

So I have a spreadsheet that was generated by Google Forms. I would like to gather all "Usernames" from column `B2:B` and put it in into a single row, it will take the column `C2:C` that has the username the same as that single row and put it in a list, so basically sum up all usernames and get row `C2:C` and put it in a list, so there will only be one row for each username. Every time there is a new username in the B2:B column, it will make another row in a non-occupied row below the formula so it will basically gather all usernames and get the column to the right (C2:C) and put that in a list. I know this seems very confusing but if you read carefully you will understand. I will probably just end up deleting this because no one will probably understand.

Here's what I am meaning...
https://i.stack.imgur.com/CZMa1.jpg (Imgur collection)

**Please note I don't want to use the Timestamp column so ignore it in the formula.**

Comment: It looks like merge gridview cells, please see this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16147963/gridview-with-merged-cells

Comment: @TonyDong Well, it helped a bit... I searched "Merge Cells in Google Sheets Formula" but I couldn't really find what I was looking for. Thanks for the help anyway!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In (say) F2 just put

```
=B2
```

and in G2 just put

```
=C2
```

Then in F3

```
=ArrayFormula(IF((ROW()-MAX(ROW(F$2:F2)*(F$2:F2<>"")))<COUNTIF(B$2:B$10,INDEX(F$2:F2,MAX(ROW(F$2:F2)*(F$2:F2<>""))-ROW(A$1),0)),"",INDEX(B$2:B$10,MATCH(0,COUNTIF(F$2:F2,B$2:B$10),0))))
```

and in G3

```
=ArrayFormula(INDEX(C$2:C$10,SMALL(IF(B$2:B$10=INDEX(F$2:F3,MAX(ROW(F$2:F3)*(F$2:F3<>""))-ROW(A$1),0),ROW(B$2:B$10)-ROW(A$1)),ROW()-MAX(ROW(F$2:F3)*(F$2:F3<>""))+1),0))
```

and pull down.

[image]

Comment: Although it's not fully automatic, it works for now. Thanks!