# Merge multiple rows into one

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

I'm using SQL server 2012. My table looks like

[image]

The different visit types can be - Completed,Bumped,No Show, Late Cancelled and Cancelled. I want to have my output as
[image]

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Paul, do you want to retrieve this data to use where? C# linq has a trick to group exactly like you want to.

Comment: SQL is not suitable for formatting data sets. It would be a really bad idea to handle this kind of operation at DB-Server level.

Comment: *Merging cells* is a concern of grids and reports, not SQL. Almost all grid controls and libraries can merge adjacent rows or columns with identical values. Where are you trying to display this data?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [GridView with merged cells](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16147963/gridview-with-merged-cells)

Comment: Even if the grid you use doesn't support merging, you can replicate it by removing borders and text, [as shown here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16774966/how-to-merge-datagridview-cell-in-winforms). Finally, if you intend to export to Excel cell merging is also available

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```
select date,
    'Completed: '+sum(case [Visit Type] when 'Completed' then [Count] else 0 end)
    +' '+char(10)+'Late Cancelled: '+sum(case [Visit Type] when 'Late Cancelled' then [Count] else 0 end)
    +' '+char(10)+'Bumped: '+sum(case [Visit Type] when 'Bumped' then [Count] else 0 end)
    +' '+char(10)+'No Show: '+sum(case [Visit Type] when 'No Show' then [Count] else 0 end)
    +' '+char(10)+'Cancelled: '+sum(case [Visit Type] when 'Cancelled' then [Count] else 0 end)
    as comment
from yourtable
group by date
```

Comment: This won't work if the data needs to be displayed in an HTML page. It probably won't work in *any* OS either expect the old MacOS - `char(10)` is `\r `. *Cell merging* isn't something that should be done using SQL

Answer (score 0):

As already said, not really the way you should be approaching this, grouping of this sort would not be done in SQL.

You can however help things along a bit by grouping the data into XML or JSON if your front end can handle that. Have a look at the following:

```
DECLARE @myTable AS TABLE (Date DATE
                          ,VisitType NVARCHAR(20)
                          ,Count INT
                          )

INSERT  INTO @myTable
VALUES  ('2018-6-3', 'Completed', 9),
        ('2018-6-3', 'Late Cancelled', 1),
        ('2018-6-3', 'No Show', 2),
        ('2018-6-13', 'Completed', 5),
        ('2018-6-13', 'Bumped', 1),
        ('2018-6-13', 'No Show', 3)

SELECT  Date
,       (SELECT VisitType, [Count] FROM @myTable B WHERE B.Date = A.Date FOR XML AUTO ) Result
FROM    @myTable A
GROUP BY DATE
```

You can play with the xml parameters to get the exact format you want. Thats well documented online.